# Texture rotating around background withut mouse in Monogame, c#

Tags: c#, monogame

Im trying to rotate a texture in Monogame ! It schould rotate around another object like doing a circle (not routate the texture it self ), it schould do a circle rotate. It schould not rotate with the mouse but continosly rotating in that radius itself. Im  new in MOnogame and a tried everything for two last days and nothing worked. Some said that i schould do somethink with Sin and Cos but i didnt get it ! Its for a project and im very lost ! I would be very very greatfull if someone could help me ! [So this logo schould routate around the background ][2]

Link to picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/gywi7teun8lqfp1/Unbenannt.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure math problem. From what i can understand, what you want is to make your texture orbit around a point, see this formula :

```
 newX = centerX + ( cosX * (pointX-centerX) + sinX * (pointY -centerY))
 newY = centerY + ( -sinX * (pointX-centerX) + cosX * (pointY -centerY))
```

With :
 `centerX` and `centerY` being the point around you want to orbit 
`cosX` and `sinX` being respectively the cosinus of the angle and the sinus of the angle
`pointX` and `pointY` being the position you want to apply rotation from (the texture position in your case)

Note that the angle should be in radians, and not in degrees.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how schould i translate it into code ?

Comment: this would work but in monogame it would be better to use a rotation matrix, it is more in the spirit of the api, plus under the covers they are doing the sin and cos for you

Answer (score 0):

Answers to this question can be found here:

[Have an object circle an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935239/monogame-have-an-object-circle-around-a-point)

There are also examples of how to use Math in MonoGames

If you want to use a matrix and let the api rotate for you you could try something like this

```
 public Vector2 RotateAboutOrigin(Vector2 point, Vector2 origin, float rotation)
 {  
   return Vector2.Transform(pointorigin,Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation))+origin;
 }
```